# Javascript sort() why are args in opposite order?

Tags: javascript

```
const n = [2, 5, 100, 4]

n.sort((a, b) => {
 console.log(a, b)
 return a - b;
})
```

```
// console log
5 2
100 5
4 100
```

Why is `a` `5` and `b` `2`, etc..?

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64396555/sorting-compare-in-chrome-vs-firefox) which asks a similar question.

Answers given amount to: "Browsers interpret the spec, therefore the order is not guaranteed". But fails to answer the question.

Comment: clearly sort callback is called that way - does it matter? note: firefox calls with the arguments in your "expected" order - yet the result is the same, the internal workings are different, so, it doesn't matter

Comment: sorry - does this answer your question? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: @MMD - that shows no reference to how the sort function is called and in what order the values are sent - because the implementation doesn't matter

Comment: the sent values doesn't matter - you just need to tell it between the two given, which one is greater.

Comment: From the [specification](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.sort): _“Step 8: Sort items using an **implementation-defined** sequence of calls to SortCompare.”, “The abstract operation SortCompare takes arguments_ x _and_ y. _It also has access to the_ comparefn _argument passed to the current invocation of the `sort` method.”_ (emphasis mine).

Comment: What more do you want? If you want to learn why a browser vendor implemented this in a certain way, go ask the maintainers or read the open source code of the browser. This is either too opinion-based or too broad for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

The standard [22.1.3.27](https://262.ecma-international.org/10.0/#sec-indexed-collections) does not specify how the compare function is being called:

> Perform an implementation-dependent sequence of calls to the [[Get]] and [[Set]] internal methods of obj, to the DeletePropertyOrThrow and HasOwnProperty abstract operation with obj as the first argument, and to SortCompare (described below)