# Array.prototype.sort() works on Firefox but not Chrome?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a Next.JS Webapp I am building. Before I save my data to a useState object to be used on my webapp, I modify it with this piece of code to sort an array of objects by a contained date field.

```
person_json[0].events.sort(({date:a}, {date:b}) => new Date(a) < new Date(b));
```

On my Firefox browser, these events show up in date order. However, when I run the application on Chrome, the dates do not get sorted. Can you explain why?

Comment: The following links might help: [Sorting / compare in Chrome vs Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64396555/sorting-compare-in-chrome-vs-firefox) ||  [How does JavaScript's sort (compareFunction) work? \[duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41121068/how-does-javascripts-sort-comparefunction-work)

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you're describing might be related to differences in how browsers handle sorting with the sort method. The Array.prototype.sort method in JavaScript is not guaranteed to be stable across all browsers when the comparison function returns 0.

In your case, the comparison function compares the dates and returns a boolean value, which might not be the best approach for consistent sorting behavior across different browsers.

To ensure cross-browser compatibility, you can modify the comparison function to return a numerical value. Here's an example:

```
person_json[0].events.sort((a, b) => {
  const dateA = new Date(a.date);
  const dateB = new Date(b.date);

  if (dateA < dateB) {
    return -1;
  } else if (dateA > dateB) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
});
```